# Nokogiri-- To remove unwanted spaces between tags having no text

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, gsub

I have a HTML content as--

```
html = "<table id=\"soa_table\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed soa-table\"><thead><tr><th>SoA</th><th id=\"423\" class=\"soa-column text-center\">V1</th><th id=\"424\" class=\"soa-column text-center\">V2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class=\"soa-row\" id=\"631\">Label 1</td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"631\" visit_id=\"423\" id=\"484\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td><td class=\"soa-element\" form_id=\"631\" visit_id=\"424\" id=\"0\"> </td></tr><tr><td class=\"soa-row\" id=\"632\">Label 2</td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"632\" visit_id=\"423\" id=\"485\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td><td class=\"soa-element\" form_id=\"632\" visit_id=\"424\" id=\"0\"> </td></tr><tr><td class=\"soa-row\" id=\"633\">Label 3</td><td class=\"soa-element\" form_id=\"633\" visit_id=\"423\" id=\"0\"> </td><td class=\"soa-element text-center\" form_id=\"633\" visit_id=\"424\" id=\"486\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-ok text-success\"></span></td></tr></tbody></table>"
```

Now I parsed it via Nokogiri and tried to gsub the spaces as---

```
Nokogiri::HTML(html).at('table').to_html.gsub(/>\s+</, "><")
```

But it doesn't works

Comment: Manipulating the raw HTML somehow defeats the purpose of using Nokogiri.

Comment: Indeed, it does actually work, but you are not saving the output to a variable.  Not that I would recommend doing this, you don't need nokogiri to compress out the spaces, just gsub.

Answer (score 2):

> remove unwanted spaces between tags having no text

I asume you mean this kind of space:

```
<td class="soa-element" form_id="631" visit_id="424" id="0"> </td>
                                                            ^
```

That's a *text node* containing a single space.

Let's use a smaller example:

```
html = '<foo>value</foo><bar> </bar>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)
```

You can use [`PP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/pp/rdoc/PP.html) to inspect the parsed document structure:

```
require 'pp'

pp doc
```

Output:

```
#(DocumentFragment:0x3fe819894018 {
  name = "#document-fragment",
  children = [
    #(Element:0x3fe819891b9c { name = "foo", children = [ #(Text "value")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe819891ae8 { name = "bar", children = [ #(Text " ")] })]
  })
```

The document contains two text nodes, one with `"value"` the other one with `" "`.

In order to remove the latter, we can traverse the document and remove all text nodes containing just whitespace:

```
doc.traverse { |node| node.remove if node.text? && node.text !~ /\S/ }
pp doc
```

Output:

```
#(DocumentFragment:0x3fe819894018 {
  name = "#document-fragment",
  children = [
    #(Element:0x3fe819891b9c { name = "foo", children = [ #(Text "value")] }),
    #(Element:0x3fe819891ae8 { name = "bar" })]
  })
```

Finally, we can serialize the document:

```
doc.to_html
#=> "<foo>value</foo><bar></bar>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove whitespace-only text nodes:

```
doc.search('//text()[normalize-space()=""]').remove
```

Update with example:

```
Nokogiri::HTML('<b></b>   <b></b>').search('//text()[normalize-space()=""]').remove
#=> [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x197ad78 "   ">]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, i.e. `doc.search('//text()[normalize-space()=""]')` returns an empty result for the OP's input.

Comment: That means there aren't any.

Comment: Right, this solution does that. I'm not sure why you're saying it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've tested it with `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html)`. Any idea why it doesn't work for a `DocumentFragment`?

Comment: I suppose document fragment has no root. Maybe `.//` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`gsub` does not substitute into the source object.  `gsub!` does.  Also, you don't need Nokogiri at all.

```
require 'nokogiri'

puts 'Needlessly using Nokogiri'
html = "<p>   </p>"
new_html = Nokogiri::HTML(html).at('p').to_html.gsub(/>\s+</, '><')
puts html
puts new_html

puts '-' * 20

puts 'Solution #1'
html = "<p>   </p>"
new_html = html.gsub(/>\s+</, '><')
puts html
puts new_html

puts '-' * 20

puts 'Solution #2'
html = "<p>   </p>"
puts html
html.gsub!(/>\s+</,'><')
puts html
```

The output of this program is:

> ```
> Needlessly using Nokogiri
> <p>   </p>
> <p></p>
> --------------------
> Solution #1
> <p>   </p>
> <p></p>
> --------------------
> Solution #2
> <p>   </p>
> <p></p>
> ```

Comment: _"you don't need Nokogiri at all"_ – you don't, but you shouldn't use regular expressions to process HTML either :-)

Comment: @Tom I appreciate your comment ,but I used nokogiri to parse html for converting '&nbsp;' into \n as gsub('&nbsp;','') doesn't works with ruby 2.3.1. Also I need to store the result into a variable i.e don't need to destruct the html

Comment: @Tom try to use the html given with gsub!(/>\s+</,'><'). You will find the spaces persist

Comment: Then the original question needs to be more complete, and I did try with your HTML and the spaces did not persist.

Comment: @Stefan whether you should use regex to process HTML or not depends on the context in which one is doing either.  What do you think happens inside Nokogiri?  Lots of regex.

Comment: _"What do you think happens inside Nokogiri?_ – I think it uses libxml2.

Comment: So the context is important.  Do you really load libxml2 and nokogiri into memory, create all those objects, do all that stack manipulation -- if you're just doing this and not any other HTML handling?